# First chess game

Tags: python, pygame, chess

I am just new to programming I just have a 2 month experience in programming and a 2 week experience with python.

This is my chess game written in python with pygame.

Can some one help me how can I improve this program ?

p.s. this is not a AI chess game it is a multiplayer game; also the checkmate condition is not yet implemented, I'd like to clean up what I have (which works as intented) before I go and implement it.

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

# defines the width and height of the display
display_width = 600
display_height = 680

# defines block width and height
block_height = 50 * 1.5
block_width = 50 * 1.5

factor = 25 * 1.5

# defines colours
white = (255, 255, 255)
d_white = (250, 250, 250)
black = (0, 0, 0)
teal = (0, 128, 128)
blue_black = (50, 50, 50)

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.update()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

selected_family = "black"


class piece:
    x = 0  # x coordinate
    y = 0  # y coordinate
    rank = ""  # rank of the piece
    life = True  # is the piece dead or alive
    family = ""  # colour of the piece (black or white)
    pic = ""  # photo of the piece

    def __init__(self, x_position, y_position, p_rank, p_family):
        self.x = x_position
        self.y = y_position
        self.rank = p_rank
        self.family = p_family


selected_piece = piece
end_piece = piece
pie = [piece(3, 7, "q", "black"), piece(0, 6, "p", "black"), piece(1, 6, "p", "black"), piece(2, 6, "p", "black"),
       piece(2, 0, "b", "white"), piece(5, 0, "b", "white"), piece(0, 0, "r", "white"), piece(7, 0, "r", "white"),
       piece(3, 6, "p", "black"), piece(4, 6, "p", "black"), piece(5, 6, "p", "black"), piece(6, 6, "p", "black"),
       piece(7, 6, "p", "black"), piece(1, 0, "k", "white"), piece(6, 0, "k", "white"), piece(4, 0, "king", "white"),
       piece(0, 1, "p", "white"), piece(1, 1, "p", "white"), piece(2, 1, "p", "white"), piece(3, 1, "p", "white"),
       piece(4, 1, "p", "white"), piece(5, 1, "p", "white"), piece(6, 1, "p", "white"), piece(7, 1, "p", "white"),
       piece(3, 0, "q", "white"), piece(2, 7, "b", "black"), piece(5, 7, "b", "black"), piece(0, 7, "r", "black"),
       piece(7, 7, "r", "black"), piece(1, 7, "k", "black"), piece(6, 7, "k", "black"), piece(4, 7, "king", "black") ]

print(pie[0].x, pie[0].y)


def initialize_piece():
    i = 0
    while i < len(pie):
        if pie[i].rank == "p" and pie[i].life:

            if pie[i].family == "white":
                img = pygame.image.load("pawn_white.png")
            else:
                img = pygame.image.load("pawn_black.png")
            game_display.blit(img, ((2 * pie[i].x) * factor, ((2 * pie[i].y) * factor)))

        elif pie[i].rank == "q" and pie[i].life:

            if pie[i].family == "white":
                img = pygame.image.load("queen_white.png")
            else:
                img = pygame.image.load("queen_black.png")
            game_display.blit(img, ((2 * pie[i].x) * factor, ((2 * pie[i].y) * factor)))
        elif pie[i].rank == "b" and pie[i].life:

            if pie[i].family == "white":
                img = pygame.image.load("bishop_white.png")
            else:
                img = pygame.image.load("bishop_black.png")
            game_display.blit(img, ((2 * pie[i].x) * factor, ((2 * pie[i].y) * factor)))
        elif pie[i].rank == "r" and pie[i].life:

            if pie[i].family == "white":
                img = pygame.image.load("rook_white.png")
            else:
                img = pygame.image.load("rook_black.png")
            game_display.blit(img, ((2 * pie[i].x) * factor, ((2 * pie[i].y) * factor)))
        elif pie[i].rank == "k" and pie[i].life:

            if pie[i].family == "white":
                img = pygame.image.load("knight_white.png")
            else:
                img = pygame.image.load("knight_black.png")
            game_display.blit(img, ((2 * pie[i].x) * factor, ((2 * pie[i].y) * factor)))
        elif pie[i].rank == "king" and pie[i].life:

            if pie[i].family == "white":
                img = pygame.image.load("king_white.png")
            else:
                img = pygame.image.load("king_black.png")
            game_display.blit(img, ((2 * pie[i].x) * factor, ((2 * pie[i].y) * factor)))
        i += 1


def clear():
    i = 0
    while i < len(pie):
        if (pie[i].x + pie[i].y) % 2 == 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(game_display, d_white, ((2 * pie[i].x + 1) * 25, ((2 * pie[i].y + 1) * 25), 12, 12))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(game_display, blue_black, ((2 * pie[i].x + 1) * 25, ((2 * pie[i].y + 1) * 25), 12, 12))

        i += 1


def move(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
    val = False
    t = 9
    final_pie = piece
    # print(final_x, "+", final_y)
    global selected_family
    fam = selected_family
    for i in range(len(pie)):
        final_pie = None
        if pie[i].x == orignal_x and pie[i].y == orignal_y and pie[i].life and pie[i].family == fam:
            for k in range(len(pie)):
                if pie[k].x == final_x and pie[k].y == final_y and pie[k].life:
                    final_pie = pie[k]
                    t = k
                    break
                    # If the pieces are not of same family then

            if pie[i].rank == 'p' and final_pie != None:
                if final_pie.family != pie[i].family and orignal_x != final_x:
                    if orignal_x + 1 == final_x or orignal_x - 1 == final_x:
                        if pie[i].family == "black":
                            direction = -1
                        else:
                            direction = 1
                        if orignal_y + direction == final_y:
                            pie[t].life = False
                            pie[i].x = final_x
                            pie[i].y = final_y
                            if pie[i].family == "white":
                                selected_family = "black"
                            else:
                                selected_family = "white"
                                clear()
                            print(pie[t].x, final_pie.y, " <--")
                else:
                    val = True

            if pie[i].rank == 'q' and final_pie != None:
                if pie[t].family != pie[i].family:
                    if check_queen(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
                        pie[t].life = False
                        pie[i].x = final_x
                        pie[i].y = final_y
                        if pie[i].family == "white":
                            selected_family = "black"
                        else:
                            selected_family = "white"
                        clear()
                        # print(pie[t].x, final_pie.y, " <--")
                        clear()
                else:
                    val = True

            if pie[i].rank == 'b' and final_pie != None:
                if pie[t].family != pie[i].family:
                    if diagonalcheck(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
                        print("yaah")
                        pie[t].life = False
                        pie[i].x = final_x
                        pie[i].y = final_y
                        if pie[i].family == "white":
                            selected_family = "black"
                        else:
                            selected_family = "white"
                        clear()
                        # print(pie[t].x, final_pie.y, " <--")
                        clear()
                else:
                    val = True

            if pie[i].rank == 'r' and final_pie != None:
                if pie[t].family != pie[i].family:
                    if check_rook(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
                        print("yaah")
                        pie[t].life = False
                        pie[i].x = final_x
                        pie[i].y = final_y
                        if pie[i].family == "white":
                            selected_family = "black"
                        else:
                            selected_family = "white"
                        clear()

                        clear()
                else:
                    val = True

            if pie[i].rank == 'k' and final_pie != None:
                if pie[t].family != pie[i].family:
                    if knight_check(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
                        print("yaah")
                        pie[t].life = False
                        pie[i].x = final_x
                        pie[i].y = final_y
                        if pie[i].family == "white":
                            selected_family = "black"
                        else:
                            selected_family = "white"
                        clear()

                        clear()
                else:
                    val = True

            if pie[i].rank == 'king' and final_pie != None:
                if pie[t].family != pie[i].family:
                    if king_check(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
                        pie[t].life = False
                        pie[i].x = final_x
                        pie[i].y = final_y
                        if pie[i].family == "white":
                            selected_family = "black"
                        else:
                            selected_family = "white"
                        clear()

                        clear()
                else:
                    val = True
    if val is False:

        for i in range(len(pie)):
            if pie[i].x == orignal_x and pie[i].y == orignal_y and pie[i].family == selected_family:
                clear()

                if pie[i].rank == "p":
                    if pie[i].family == "black":
                        direction = -1
                    else:
                        direction = 1
                    if orignal_y == 6 or orignal_y == 1:
                        if final_y == orignal_y + (2 * direction) and final_x == orignal_x:
                            rigt_upfront = False
                            for k in range(len(pie)):
                                if pie[k].y == orignal_y + direction and pie[k].x == orignal_x:
                                    rigt_upfront = True
                            if not rigt_upfront:
                                pie[i].x = final_x
                                pie[i].y = final_y
                                if pie[i].family == "white":
                                    selected_family = "black"
                                else:
                                    selected_family = "white"
                    if final_y == orignal_y + direction and final_x == orignal_x:
                        pie[i].x = final_x
                        pie[i].y = final_y
                        if pie[i].family == "white":
                            selected_family = "black"
                        else:
                            selected_family = "white"

                if pie[i].rank == "q":
                    if check_queen(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
                        pie[i].x = final_x
                        pie[i].y = final_y
                        if pie[i].family == "white":
                            selected_family = "black"
                        else:
                            selected_family = "white"

                if pie[i].rank == "b":
                    if diagonalcheck(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
                        if diagonal(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
                            pie[i].x = final_x
                            pie[i].y = final_y
                            if pie[i].family == "white":
                                selected_family = "black"
                            else:
                                selected_family = "white"

                if pie[i].rank == "r":
                    if check_rook(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
                        pie[i].x = final_x
                        pie[i].y = final_y
                        if pie[i].family == "white":
                            selected_family = "black"
                        else:
                            selected_family = "white"

                if pie[i].rank == "k":
                    if knight_check(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
                        pie[i].x = final_x
                        pie[i].y = final_y
                        if pie[i].family == "white":
                            selected_family = "black"
                        else:
                            selected_family = "white"

                if pie[i].rank == "king":
                    if king_check(orignal_x, orignal_y, final_x, final_y):
                        pie[i].x = final_x
                        pie[i].y = final_y
                        if pie[i].family == "white":
                            selected_family = "black"
                        else:
                            selected_family = "white"


def check_queen(x_i, y_i, x_f, y_f):
    col = True

    if x_i == x_f and y_i != y_f:
        a = 0
        b = 0
        if y_i > y_f:
            a = y_i
            b = y_f
        else:
            a = y_f
            b = y_i

        for i in range(b, a):
            if i == b:
                col = True
            else:
                for k in range(len(pie)):
                    if pie[k].x == x_f and pie[k].y == i and pie[k].life:
                        col = False
    elif x_i != x_f and y_i == y_f:
        a = 0
        b = 0
        if x_i > x_f:
            a = x_i
            b = x_f
        else:
            a = x_f
            b = x_i

        for i in range(b, a):
            if i == b:
                col = True
            else:
                for k in range(len(pie)):
                    if pie[k].y == y_f and pie[k].x == i and pie[k].life:
                        col = False
    elif diagonalcheck(x_i, y_i, x_f, y_f):
        if diagonal(x_i, y_i, x_f, y_f):
            col = True
    else:
        col = False
    return col


def king_check(x_i, y_i, x_f, y_f):
    col = False

    if x_i+1 == x_f and y_i == y_f:
        col = True
    elif x_i + 1 == x_f and y_i +1 == y_f:
        col = True
    elif x_i + 1 == x_f and y_i -1 == y_f:
        col = True
    elif x_i-1 == x_f and y_i == y_f:
        col = True
    elif x_i - 1 == x_f and y_i +1 == y_f:
        col = True
    elif x_i - 1 == x_f and y_i -1 == y_f:
        col = True
    elif x_i  == x_f and y_i -1 == y_f:
        col = True
    elif x_i  == x_f and y_i -1 == y_f:
        col = True
    elif x_i  == x_f and y_i -1 == y_f:
        col = True
    return col

def check_rook(x_i, y_i, x_f, y_f):
    col = True

    if x_i == x_f and y_i != y_f:
        a = 0
        b = 0
        if y_i > y_f:
            a = y_i
            b = y_f
        else:
            a = y_f
            b = y_i

        for i in range(b, a):
            if i == b:
                col = True
            else:
                for k in range(len(pie)):
                    if pie[k].x == x_f and pie[k].y == i and pie[k].life:
                        col = False
    elif x_i != x_f and y_i == y_f:
        a = 0
        b = 0
        if x_i > x_f:
            a = x_i
            b = x_f
        else:
            a = x_f
            b = x_i

        for i in range(b, a):
            if i == b:
                col = True
            else:
                for k in range(len(pie)):
                    if pie[k].y == y_f and pie[k].x == i and pie[k].life:
                        col = False
    else:
        col = False
    return col

def knight_check(i_x, i_y, f_x, f_y):
    t = False
    if i_x+1 == f_x and i_y+2 == f_y:
        t = True
    elif i_x+1 == f_x and  i_y-2 == f_y:
        t = True
    elif i_x-1 == f_x and  i_y+2 == f_y:
        t = True
    elif i_x-1 == f_x and  i_y-2 == f_y:
        t = True
    elif i_x+2 == f_x and  i_y+1 == f_y:
        t = True
    elif i_x+2 == f_x and  i_y-1 == f_y:
        t = True
    elif i_x-2 == f_x and  i_y+1 == f_y:
        t = True
    elif i_x-2 == f_x and  i_y-1 == f_y:
        t = True
    return t

def diagonalcheck(i_x, i_y, f_x, f_y):
    dir_x = 0
    dir_y = 0
    th = False
    a = i_x
    b = i_y
    if i_x < f_x:
        dir_x = +1
    elif i_x > f_x:
        dir_x = -1
    if i_y < f_y:
        dir_y = 1
    elif i_y > f_y:
        dir_y = -1
    while a < 8 and a >= 0 and b < 8 and b >= 0 and dir_x != 0 and dir_y != 0:
        if a == f_x and b == f_y:
            print("yes")
            th = True
        a += dir_x
        b += dir_y
    return th


def diagonal(i_x, i_y, f_x, f_y):
    dir_x = 0
    dir_y = 0
    th = True
    a = i_x
    b = i_y

    if i_x < f_x:
        dir_x = +1
    elif i_x > f_x:
        dir_x = -1
    if i_y < f_y:
        dir_y = 1
    elif i_y > f_y:
        dir_y = -1
    print("a =", a, ",b =", b, ",dir x =", dir_x, ",dir y =", dir_y, ",final x =", f_x, "final y =", f_y)
    while a != f_x and b != f_y:
        for i in range(len(pie)):
            print("a =", a, ",b =", b)
            if pie[i].x == a + dir_x and pie[i].y == b + dir_y:
                th = False


        a = a + dir_x
        b = b + dir_y
    if i_x == f_x or i_y == f_y:
        th = False
    return th


def board_draw():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    game_display.fill(black)


    selected_family = "black"
    for i in range(8):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            j = 0
        else:
            j = 1
        while j < 8:
            pygame.draw.rect(game_display, d_white, (i * 50 * 1.5, j * 50 *1.5, block_width, block_height))
            j += 2

def select_block(x_cursor, y_cursor):
    selected_piece = None
    for i in range(len(pie)):
        if pie[i].x == x_cursor and pie[i].y == y_cursor:

            return pie[i]


def game():
    selec = False
    global selected_family
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                a = pos[0] // 75
                b = pos[1] // 75
                pygame.draw.rect(game_display, teal, (a * 50 * 1.5, b * 50 * 1.5, block_width, block_height))
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.03)

                if not selec:
                    selected_piece = select_block(a, b)
                    selec = True
                    if selected_piece is not None:
                        print(selected_piece.x, " ", selected_piece.y)

                    else:
                        selec = False
                else:
                    if selected_piece is not None:
                        move(selected_piece.x, selected_piece.y, a, b)
                    selec = False
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        board_draw()

        initialize_piece()
        myfont = pygame.font.Font("sans.ttf", 30)
        string = selected_family +"'s turn"
        label = myfont.render(string, 1, white)


        game_display.blit(label, (20, 620))
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(20)


game()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function `initialize_piece` could be way simpler if you used a dictionary to map from the piece rank to the file name and used [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to supply the family into the string:

```
file_names = {"p": "pawn_{}.png", ...}            

def initialize_piece():
    for piece in pie:
        if piece.life:
            img = pygame.image.load(file_names[piece.rank].format(piece.family)
            game_display.blit(img, ((2 * piece.x) * factor, ((2 * piece.y) * factor)))
```

This could be simplified even further if every piece had for example `"pawn"` as rank, so that you could add a `file_name` [property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work) (and a `position` property):

```
class piece:
    x = 0  # x coordinate
    y = 0  # y coordinate
    rank = ""  # rank of the piece, e.g. "pawn"
    life = True  # is the piece dead or alive
    family = ""  # colour of the piece ("black" or "white")
    pic = ""  # photo of the piece

    def __init__(self, x_position, y_position, p_rank, p_family):
        self.x = x_position
        self.y = y_position
        self.rank = p_rank
        self.family = p_family

    @property
    def file_name(self):
        return "{self.rank}_{self.family}.png".format(self=self)

    @property
    def position(self):
        return ((2 * self.x) * factor, ((2 * self.y) * factor))
```

With this it would become:

```
def initialize_piece():
    for piece in pie:
        if piece.life:
            img = pygame.image.load(piece.file_name)
            game_display.blit(img, piece.position)
```

In addition to this, you should work on your style. Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It recommends using `CAPITAL_LETTERS` for constants, `lower_case` for variables and functions and `PascalCase` for classes.

In addition, you should get rid of your global variables as much as possible, they make it very hard to follow the program flow. Instead, pass the variables as arguments where necessary:

```
def initialize_piece(pieces):
    for piece in pieces:
        if piece.life:
            img = pygame.image.load(piece.file_name)
            game_display.blit(img, piece.position)
```

What would make it even better is if the image was only loaded once per piece:

```
class Piece:

    def __init__(self, x, y, rank, family):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        # rank of the piece, e.g. "pawn"
        self.rank = rank
        # colour of the piece ("black" or "white")
        self.family = family
        self.file_name = "{}_{}.png".format(rank, family)
        self.img = pygame.image.load(self.file_name) 

    @property
    def position(self):
        return ((2 * self.x) * factor, ((2 * self.y) * factor))


def initialize_piece(pieces):
    for piece in pieces:
        if piece.life:
            game_display.blit(piece.img, piece.position)
```

Here I also removed the unnecessary initializations in the class, you don't need to initialize variables in Python. The comments could be moved to a `docstring`, for documentation purposes.

Finally, something I have already done above, you should [learn how to iterate properly](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html). In Python iterating over the indices of a list (and even worse, using a `while` loop where a `for` loop would be a lot easier) is frowned upon.

Instead of any of these:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

i = 0
while i < len(l):
    do_something(l[i])
    i += 1

for i in range(len(l)):
    do_something(l[i])
```

you should just use:

```
for x in l:
    do_something(x)
```

If you really need the index, use `enumerate`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    do_something(i, x)
```

I will leave the rest for somebody else...